# Counter in time

Tags: python, time, count

This might sound simple, but we are having a hard time doing this. we want to implement a counter for our time, so for every 20 min count +1. An example could be to have a string: `0 days 00:20:00` and a missing value = (counter). Below is an example of what we want to achieve:

```
 |  0 days 00:20:00  |  MISSING VALUE = 1
```

Example 2:

```
|  0 days 01:20:00  |  MISSING VALUE = 4
```

**UPDATED AND NOW WORKING:**

```
index = pd.date_range(start=firstTime.min(), end=lastTime.max(), freq='20T')

for x in index:
    timediff = (x + datetime.timedelta(minutes=20)) - first_datetime
    timediv = timediff / datetime.timedelta(minutes=20)
    print (f' |  {timediff}  |  MISSING VALUE = {timediv}')
```

PRINTS:

```
x + datetime.timedelta(minutes=20): 2019-07-27 23:00:00
first_datetime: 2019-07-27 22:40:00
timediff: 0 days 00:20:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime.timedelta` for this purpose. For example:

```py
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
previous_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)

(current_time-previous_time)/datetime.timedelta(minutes=20)
```

will give you `3.0`. To not get fractions, you can apply `math.floor` on the result.